# Ruby and Heroku JS and CSS files not loading

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

/assets/application.css

```
/*
  *= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/
  *= require_tree
*/
```

/assets/application.js

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/
//= require shim
//= require dim-the-lights
//= require main
//= require custom-playlists-dropdown
//= require user
//= require player
//= require unity
//= require playlist
//= require video
//= require import
//= require tabs
//= require report
//= require custom-playlist-settings
//= require history
//= require whats-hot
;
```

My rake assets:precompile command result is :

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rub  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake assets                                                                      :precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:45:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:23:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-import-0.2.11/lib/activerecord-import.rb:4:i                                                                      n `establish_connection_with_activerecord_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `bl                                                                      ock (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb                                                                      :36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb                                                                      :36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb                                                                      :26:in `on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `bl                                                                      ock in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance                                                                      _exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in                                                                       run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_init                                                                      ializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initializ                                                                      e!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `m                                                                      ethod_missing'
/home/rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25                                                                      1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25                                                                      1:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:23                                                                      6:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25                                                                      1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_e                                                                      nvironment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2                                                                       levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:89:in `block (                                                                      2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (                                                                      3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/...]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rak                                                                      e_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_                                                                      or_reboot_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (                                                                      2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
root@plak1:/home/rails# uptime
 22:23:34 up  4:14,  2 users,  load average: 2.02, 2.04, 2.05
root@plak1:/home/rails# bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rake assets                                                                      :precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:45:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:39:in `resolve_string_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:23:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/                                                                      abstract/connection_specification.rb:127:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-import-0.2.11/lib/activerecord-import.rb:4:i                                                                      n `establish_connection_with_activerecord_import'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:76:in `bl                                                                      ock (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb                                                                      :36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb                                                                      :36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb                                                                      :26:in `on_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `bl                                                                      ock in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance                                                                      _exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in                                                                       run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_init                                                                      ializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initializ                                                                      e!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `m                                                                      ethod_missing'
/home/rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25                                                                      1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25                                                                      1:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:23                                                                      6:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:25                                                                      1:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_e                                                                      nvironment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2                                                                       levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:89:in `block (                                                                      2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in `block (                                                                      3 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/...]
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rak                                                                      e_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_                                                                      or_reboot_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (                                                                      2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My website looking like : http://www.plak1.com/

Files looking like : 
http://www.plak1.com/assets/application.css
Please check my files and website. thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Comment: its not solve my problem

Comment: have you precompiled assets?

Comment: `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: I have it but not loading.http://www.plak1.com/assets/application.js

Comment: I add my rake assets:precompile results on my question, please look again. thank you.